# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () - SCRIPT - WordPress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

on my wordpress site using an external cookie service, they provide me with a script to insert into the head tag

```
<script src='https://acconsento.click/script.js' id='acconsento-script' data-key='dBLtIvrsCoonhdR1zC1boEzG4YVBO1ebja0gFyOW'></script>
```

The problem is that a popup should appear to accept cookies, but this does not happen.
In the browser console I saw the following error message:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Even on the network you can see a blocked request, I'll attach all the screens, to see for yourself the link is [caseigerolalogisticspark.com](https://caseigerolalogisticspark.com/)

By inspecting any page you can see the error message
[image]
[image]

I insert the HT access file here, but it should be the standard WP one

I thought it was an error with my GoDaddy hosting provider, something related to DNS pointing or you have a firewall, but they say that everything is ok and that nothing is blocking the request.
What do you recommend me to do?

Comment: Can you share what you're trying to do with those cookies?

Comment: You should contact your vendor to solve this. One thing I do see is that right before the 403 is the message `no viewer id found`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.